# Regex remove plus addressing + from email address

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I want to remove everything from the `+` up to the `@`, including the `+`, but not the `@`

The closest that I have been able to get is using this between regex.

```py
>>> email = "garry+filter@gmail.com"
>>> re.sub(r'\+[^)]*\@', '', email)

garrygmail.com
```

Comment: got so focused on the regex i forgot what was getting added back in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `@` in the replacement string, rather than an empty string.

```
re.sub(r'\+[^)]*@', '@', email)
```

BTW, there's no need to escape `@`.